# IIS Timeout when running an exe from a webapplication

Tags: c#, iis, exe

I am **calling** an **exe inside a webapplication**. When I debug the webapplication I am able to get the desired results in visual studio. But when I published the webApplication to IIS and run the webpage from IIS, the control exists from the webpage before the exe finishes.

Like the exe gets started but at end it prints a message that the task is completed that is not present when run in IIS.
I have tried all these

```
cmdProcess.WaitForExit()
Thread.Sleep(200000) // and then read 
cmdProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() 
while (!cmdProcess.HasExited) { readline one by one}
Server.ScriptTimeout = 200000;
```

But nothing works always the control exists after starting the exe and nothing gets printed.Can someone help on this.

Also tried setting timeout in the IIS 
Connection time out to 20000 secs

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally running the website in a App pool under my credentials fixed the timeout issue ,but I have been running all my webpages under default app pool don't know how they all work and this didn't work and caused timeouts.